# Can I configure yii2 function afterAction to return my api data?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am working on my yii2 api and I was looking for a way to get data from my controller actions. This is a sample of what I need on my response in json or xml.

```
{"success": true,
 "message": {data},
 "session": "U0phRm51az",
 "metadata": "metadata"
}
```

I am getting message from the controller whereas success checks whether response is OK, session is the session data and metadata is other data.
My actions looks like these.

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $data = array();
}
```

All these use the same functions so I do not want to repeat in all actions. I would like to know how to get `$data` from each action using `afterAction` or `beforeSend` event of the response component on my module class *(not config file)*. If this is not possible, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actions return data as an array, you can add more stuff to that array in `afterAction` method of your controller.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    //...
    //$data contains an array
    return [
        'data' => $data
    ];
}

public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    $result['session'] = '...';
    $result['metadata'] = '...';
    return $result;
}
```